# How to hide addThis plugin on vertical scroll

Tags: html, css, user-interface, social-networking, addthis

I'm using [addThis social plugin](http://www.addthis.com/social-plugins) on [my blog](http://blog.nistencorp.com/). I believe the plugin is floating at a fixed position as I see in it's `css` file.

I don't think I can control that file. Correct me, if I'm wrong.

> **Problem:** how do I let it go upwards *and hide* after scrolling down.

This is not a highly critical problem but I do not want our readers to get annoyed with that sticky thing.

Comment: So you do not want its potion to be fixed?? But you want in left corner right??

Comment: You got my point @hemanthmouli

Comment: See the answer i have posted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean to hide the Sharing Sidebar tool when scrolling down the page? If so, unfortunately we don't offer any support for it. The Sharing Sidebar tool was designed to appear at the leftmost or rightmost side of the page. But you're welcome to apply your own CSS/JavaScript to any of our existing elements.  I'll pass your feedback along to our team.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The position of `.atss` Class is fixed you may may uses JQuery to make it to `position:absolute`

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".atss").css("position","absolute");
});
</script>
```

Include This script in your website!! You can feel the diffrence.

Comment: Actually that was perfect!! Anyhow try this `css({"position":"absolute","top": "20%", "width" :"48px", "z-index": "100020"});`

Answer (score 1):

> **[!important](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)** css

The issue was resolved by using [!important](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/) css declaration in the site's [main css file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nistenblog/nistenblog.github.io/master/style.scss)

Below is the snapshot of the same:

```
//Keep addThis unsticky
.atss{
      position:absolute !important; 
}
```

Thanks to [hemnath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5039410/hemnath-mouli) and [ribin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5109919/ribin-babu) for their opinions.

Comment: Yes, `position:absolute` but with [!important](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/) was needed. jQuery did not worked actually. Thanks.